# R or SQL select records having different value for different category

Tags: sql, r, select, hive, subset

I have dataframe/or table like this

```
RowNumber   Category    Value 
   1 .        A          12
   2 .        A           3 
   3 .        B          24     
   4.         B          32
   5 .        B          11
   6 .        C          30   
   7 .        D           2
   8 .        D          33
```

..

Use SQL (Hive) or R  hope get guidance of both language:
Select record based on Having different cut off point for different Category

For Category A, I want to choose the Value >= 10
but for all the other category, B,C,D need to choose the value >= 20

the results:

```
RowNumber   Category    Value 
   1 .        A          12
   3 .        B          24     
   4.         B          32
   6 .        C          30   
   8 .        D          33
```

How could I do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried the simple answer - `WHERE (Category = 'A' AND Value>=10) OR (Value>=20)`?

Comment: @user7694774, why/how are you choosing value>=10 for Category A and value>=20 for the other categories?  Is it fixed or dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R it can be done using:

```
df <- data.frame(RowNumber = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8), Category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"), Value = c(12, 3, 24, 32, 11, 30, 2, 33))
df[df$Category == "A" & df$Value >= 10 | df$Category != "A" & df$Value >= 20, ]
```

You'll get desired results:

```
    RowNumber Category  Value
1         1        A    12
3         3        B    24
4         4        B    32
6         6        C    30
8         8        D    33
```

Comment: wouldn't it require brackets?

Comment: Worked without the brackets. You can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives.

```
library(sqldf)

# 1
sqldf("select * from DF 
       where (Category = 'A' and Value >= 10) or (not Category = 'A' and Value >= 20)")

# 2
sqldf("select * from DF where Value >= (case when Category = 'A' then 10 else 20 end)")

# 3
sqldf("select * from DF where Value >= (10 * (not Category = 'A') + 10)")

# 4
subset(DF, (Category == "A" & Value >= 10) | (Category != "A" & Value >= 20))

# 5
subset(DF, Value >= ifelse(Category == "A", 10, 20))

# 6
subset(DF, Value >= 10 * (Category != "A") + 10)
```

Any of the above give:

```
  RowNumber Category Value
1         1        A    12
2         3        B    24
3         4        B    32
4         6        C    30
5         8        D    33
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "RowNumber   Category    Value 
   1        A          12
   2        A           3 
   3        B          24     
   4        B          32
   5        B          11
   6        C          30   
   7        D           2
   8        D          33"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple query

```
select c1,c2 from tbl where c2 >= 10 and c1 = 'A' 
union all
select c1,c2 from tbl where c2 >= 20 and c1 != 'A' 

+---------+---------+--+
| _u1.c1  | _u1.c2  |
+---------+---------+--+
| A       | 12      |
| B       | 24      |
| B       | 32      |
| C       | 30      |
| D       | 33      |
+---------+---------+--+
```